# Is there a way navigate directly to a section in an Orbeon form?

Tags: orbeon

This would save loads of time when testing a specfic section which is far down the form and the form is configured in a Wizard View.

I just wondered whether there is a querystring parameter or xpath setting to put in xforms-inspector which will save us endless clicks on the Next button! So far the best way I have found is to disable the Wizard View so that the form shows vertically.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported, but it sounds like a worthwhile feature to have, and I've created an [RFE for this feature](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2848).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have to click next all the time, you should be able to just click on the section name in the table of contents.

Comment: We have hidden the table of contents to enforce sections to be visited in sequence.